# Asking endorsement from a previous interviewer from the same organization for a new position

Tags: recruitment, references

I was interviewed by an organization a while back but was rejected. They were kind enough to give me feedback stating that though my candidature was promising they got a candidate with more experience. It was very disappointing for me.

There is another new position in the same organization, probably a different group, but is more of an entry-level position, but preferably some experience. I believe it suits better since I have some but not a lot of experience.

Is it OK to request the previous interviewer for an endorsement? He is connected to me over Linkedin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it OK to request the previous interviewer for an endorsement?

You could, but it seems unnecessary, and could even backfire. Considering that your interaction with your previous interviewer ended in rejection, you may inadvertently be calling attention to that fact.

> They were kind enough to give me feedback stating that though my candidature was promising they got a candidate with more experience.

This may very well be true, but you can't really put much faith in such feedback. They are merely trying to soften the blow of the decision, and have no incentive to give brutally honest feedback. This is why you can't assume the interviewer would provide a positive endorsement.

> It was very disappointing for me.

That's understandable, but try not to take it personally. Candidates are rejected for any number of reasons, many of which you have no control over. It's possible they were looking for someone with a very specific skillset, or they have set their expectations for a candidate too high.

A job search will invariably have multiple rejections, but in the end, you only need a single yes.